# Regex match_all phrase or tag inside another tag using mask?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have an HTML like:

```
<html>
    <span class="b-serp-url__item">newdomain.com</span>
    <span class="b-serp-url__item">USA</span>
    <span class="b-serp-url__item">U.S.A.</span>
    <span class="b-serp-url__item">new<a href="#1">bad.com</a>USA</span>
    <span class="b-serp-url__item">new<b>domain</b>.com</span>
    ...
</html>
```

How I can match content of the `<SPAN>` tag only if it contain domain name or domain name plus `<B>` tag? So I'd like REGEXP match `new<b>domain</b>.com` and  `new<b>domain</b>.com` in example above.

I tried to use `<span class="b-serp-url__item">(?:(?!<[^b]+).*?)\.(?:(?!<[^b]+).*?)</span>` but it also match `new<a href="#1">bad.com</a>USA`. Can someone suggest how to do so using regex only?

Comment: Don't use regexp to process HTML, use a DOM parser.

Comment: @Barmar , how DOM can help to differentiate domain name from usual string? REGEXP is more simple way to do this task (without loops and substring checking).

Comment: Use the DOM parser to find all the SPAN tags, then loop through them checking the contents.

Comment: @Barmar , it's too complicated. I can simply strip `<b>` tag and match using `#<span>([a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,4})</span>#`. But i'd like to do this task using REGEX only.